# Table only get drawn once

Tags: java, javascript, google-visualization

I have a form where the user can choose a host:

```
<div id="hostChart"></div>

<form onsubmit="return false">  
<input type='text' id='hostForm'/>
<input type='button' 
onclick="drawHost(document.getElementById('hostForm').value)" value='Submit' />
</form>
```

And a function which draws a table with a column 'host' with only those rows which their 'host' cell equals the user input:

```
function drawHost(hostForm) {
    var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      dataSourceUrl: 'data',
      query: 'where host="'+hostForm+'"',
      options: {'title': 'hosts'},
      containerId: 'hostChart'
    });
    wrapper.draw()
  }
```

However, the table gets drawn correctly when I submit a host the first time. When I try to submit a different host to get a different table, the table instead becomes an empty table (with only the headline row, and no host rows). Do you have any idea why that happens?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your data source is not returning any rows of data.  Debug the output on that to confirm.

Comment: The question is why is it not returning any rows

Comment: You have to debug the data source to find out why.

Comment: I input the data, and I put in a valid datum (that exists in the table)

Comment: I mean you have to look at what your server is doing.  Is it interpreting the query string correctly?  Is it processing the query correctly?  Does that query return results to the server?  If so, what is preventing the server from outputting those rows of data?